# I am unable to create a virtual environment using python-virtualenv

Tags: 16.04, python

Currently I have updated my laptop with ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 64bt  version.

I have install python 2.7 and everything and try everything, but virtualevn command throwing error   like given bellow while working fine with ubntu 14.04 please suggest and best solution to  resolve it.

currently i have tried many thing to resolve this problem like given bellow:
uninstalled setuptools and virutalenv and many dependencies and reinstalled as suggested by various post.

```
New python executable in /home/jai/Desktop/jai/jai/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/jai/Desktop/jai/jai/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 43, in SOCKSProxyManager
    raise InvalidSchema("Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.")
InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==15.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/jai/Desktop/jai/jai/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here (as I see it) is you're trying to use python 2.7 to run virtualenv when the whole point of virtualenv from the point of view of us post-10.10 ubuntu/debian branch users is to be able to compile python 2.7 programs in our python 3 (preinstalled and part of the system) environment without installing python 2.7 locally (which messes up the system beyond repair almost always).

Second bad practice I see here is an ubuntu update. Looks like it worked here (but again this feature almost always doesn't and will mess up your system) but you should use the Live USB install method to upgrade to new versions.

Anyways I recommend checking a couple of prerequisites to having python 2.7 compiles work :

32 bit arch needs to be enabled :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

pip needs to be up to date (installing does not do this, this needs to be run after installing it) :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

You need to have any and all possible dependencies from the pip build solved. Possible MIA are :

```
libonig2 autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-pip python-qt4 python-qt4-gl python-numpy python-matplotlib libgle3 python-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python-ipaddress python-enum34 python-pathlib python-py python-pycparser python-dateutil python-cffi libappindicator1 python-gpgme libindicator7 wget  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386 liblua5.1-0-dev liblua50-dev liblualib50-dev python-pyside.qtwebkit libgnutls30 libgnutls30:i386 virtualenv build-essential dh-make
```

to install some of those you'll need partners multiverse and basic apt-get setup:

```
sudo sed -i 's/# deb http:\/\/archive.canonical.com/deb http:\/\/archive.canonical.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
yes N | sudo dpkg --configure -a
#only if necessary
#sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

and you need to be inside virtualenv before running the other pip commands.

best of luck ! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer kindly please check my method through which I solved my problem.

Comment: alright. this makes me even more curious as to if `pip install --upgrade pip ` for a vanilla `apt install pip` would have solved your issue.

Comment: "pip install --upgrade pip"  is showing                                              
 "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

Comment: on your current new version you got straight from python.org setup tools, yes, I was rather wondering about the one you get from apt-get

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a long I have find a solution if any one stuck in future can follow steps bellow:

I got same problem than I find that all this is happening because of the setuptools and wheels than:

1. I have uninstall setuptools and wheels from pip
2. also from the "apt-get remove wheel setuptools virutalenv (if they exist in my case wheels and setuptools both were existed and may be conflicting each other from pip and apt-get installations)
3. download

   - setuptools-35.0.2 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads
   - virutalenv-15.1.0 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
4. install both the tools freshly

This method solved my problem both in my Desktop and laptop. 
 
This solution I have posted here also:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/876